# What's the difference between dir() and __dir__?

Tags: python

in python what's the difference between `dir()` function and `__dir__` attribute in python?

```
>>> 2 .__dir__()
['__divmod__', 'real', '__rxor__', '__floor__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__lt__', '__ceil__', '__repr__', '__reduce_ex__', '__rpow__', '__rand__', '__truediv__', '__subclasshook__', '__doc__', '__radd__', '__or__', '__pow__', '__trunc__', '__rrshift__', '__delattr__', '__reduce__', '__rlshift__', 'conjugate', '__xor__', '__rtruediv__', '__rfloordiv__', '__ge__', '__setattr__', '__class__', 'bit_length', '__neg__', '__mod__', '__int__', '__pos__', 'from_bytes', '__format__', '__rmul__', '__lshift__', '__rsub__', '__new__', '__add__', '__floordiv__', 'imag', 'to_bytes', 'numerator', '__dir__', '__abs__', '__init__', '__sizeof__', '__getnewargs__', '__getattribute__', '__invert__', '__gt__', '__rshift__', '__ne__', '__rdivmod__', '__mul__', '__and__', '__sub__', '__rmod__', '__round__', '__ror__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__bool__', '__str__', 'denominator']
>>> dir(2)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
```

Comment: `2 .__dir__()` results in an error for me (`has no attribute '__dir__'`).  How come?

Comment: you should have space between 2 and dot!

Comment: I have.  And I prefer to use `(2).__dir__()` anyway for such things.  But nevertheless my Python 2.7 and my Python 3.2 both have no `__dir__` in `int` values.  Btw, without a space you'd get a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dir` calls `__dir__` internally:

```
In [1]: class Hello():
   ...:     def __dir__(self):
   ...:         return [1,2,3]
   ...:     

In [2]: dir(Hello())
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: If your answer was true, the result of both would be identical, wouldn't they?

Comment: @Alfe yes, modulo any further processing done by `dir()`, like sorting

Comment: This pattern used for other functions too. `str(obj)` calls `obj.__str__()` and `x < y` calls `x.__lt__(y)`. You can see a complete list [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Comment: @Alfe if you sort what is returned by `dir` and `__dir__` and you test for equality it would return `True`. 
`a = sorted(func.__dir__())`
`b = sorted(dir(func))`
`print(a, len(a), '\n')`
`print(b, len(b), '\n')`
`print(a == b)`

Answer (score 15):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) explain it:

> If the object has a method named __dir__(), this method will be called and must return the list of attributes. This allows objects that implement a custom __getattr__() or __getattribute__() function to customize the way dir() reports
>   their attributes.
>
> If the object does not provide __dir__(), the function tries its best to gather information from the object’s __dict__ attribute, if defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a custom __getattr__().

Answer (score 4):

dir calls `__dir__` method if it is present,
from [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) :

> dir([object])¶ Without arguments, return the list of names in the
>   current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of
>   valid attributes for that object.
>
> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called
>   and must return the list of attributes. This allows objects that
>   implement a custom `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()` function to
>   customize the way `dir()` reports their attributes.
>
> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its best
>   to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if
>   defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not
>   necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a
>   custom `__getattr__()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out that the `__dir__` on many objects cannot be customized, so if you call it directly there is no opportunity to place a shim/wrapper in there.

It's easy to replace the builtin `dir` and give it some special powers if you need to. Tricks like this can be very useful when debugging.