# Is it bad practice to define a __dir__ function at a python module level?

Tags: python, styles, idioms

I have a main function that dynamically imports a module in another file using `importlib` and then uses the `dir` built in method to look at attributes of that module. Is it bad to manually define the `__dir()__` magic method in the module (file) itself?

main.py

```
import importlib

def main():
    module = importlib.import_module("foo")
    attributes = dir(module)
    print(attributes)
```

foo.py

```
def __dir()__:
    return [s]

s = "bar"
```

Is it looked down upon in the Python community to define `dir` at the module level as I have shown above?

Comment: no its inavlid defining double dunder method like this. go through https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/role-underscore-python and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703335/whats-the-difference-between-dir-and-dir

Comment: It's perfectly valid to define a custom `__dir__` function for a module.  You would do this if you wanted to display a list of module attributes different to those returned by the default module `__dir__`.