# Find the combination Geometric Sequence number in the ratio of 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, sequence

By given permission class, is there any better method to enchant my list_permission method that i can find out available permission

What i have tried:

```
class Permission:
    READ = 1
    WRITE = 2
    EDIT = 4
    DELETE = 8

sum = 0
def has_permission(num, perm):
    """
    Return boolean for permission checking
    >>> has_permission(Permission.Read)
    assume sum = 6
    False
    """
    return num & perm == perm

def add_permission(num, perm):
    """
    sum permission number
    >>> add_permission(Permission.Read)
    sum + 1
    """
    return num += perm

def list_permission(num):
    pers = (per for per in dir(Permission) if not per.startswith("__"))
    lists = []
    for value in pers:
        if(has_permission(num, getattr(Permission, value))):
            lists.append(value)
    return lists


> print(list_permission(6))
> # [WRITE, EDIT]
```

Comment: I don't see how's your `has_permission` method is ever useful: `6 & 2 == 6` --> `False`

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest  i tot(6 & 2) will be 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small optimization might be to use `Permission.__dict__` instead of `dir(Permission)`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703335/whats-the-difference-between-dir-and-dir) to know the difference between `dir()` and `__dir__`?

```
def list_permission(num):
    lists = []
    for key, val in Permission.__dict__.items():
        # Changed "__" to "_" in key.startswith.
        if not key.startswith("_") and has_permission(num, val):
            lists.append(key)
    return lists
```

---

If you need to access `list_permission` frequently and it is okay to use some more memory, then do:

```
def list_permission(num, cache={}):
    if num in cache:
        return cache[num]

    permissions = []
    for key, val in Permission.__dict__.items():
        # Changed "__" to "_" in key.startswith.
        if not key.startswith("_") and has_permission(num, val):
            permissions.append(key)

    cache[num] = permissions

    return permissions
```

---

> By given permission class, is there any better method to enchant my list_permission method that i can find out available permission

If it is okay to modify the `Permission` class, then use `Enum` as georg suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942183/5099803).

Comment: Thx for your suggestions, btw what do you mean `pre-calculating all the 16 possibilities` and `list_permission just do dictionary lookup`

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

```
from enum import Enum

class Permission(Enum):
    READ = 1
    WRITE = 2
    EDIT = 4
    DELETE = 8
```

and then

```
def list_permission(num):
    return [
        p.name
        for p in Permission
        if has_permission(num, p.value)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to "interpret" a numeric value into its possible set of permissions and get the result as a list of such permission key-words.

## Solution

Since, you assign values `(1, 2, 4, 8)` which are basically `(2**0, 2**1, 2**2, 2**3)`, this can be modeled using a **`decimal to binary`** conversion. The following function, `get_permissions(pnum)` will give you the desired output.

```py
get_permissions(pnum = 7, permissions_dict = None)
```

**Output**:

```
['READ', 'WRITE', 'EDIT']
```

#### Handling An Edge-Case

It also takes care of an edge case, when you provide `pnum` greater than maximum allowed value, which in this case is **`15`**.

```py
get_permissions(pnum = 19, permissions_dict = None)
```

**Output**:

```
WARNING::: MAX allowed value of pnum = 15
['READ', 'WRITE', 'EDIT', 'DELETE']
```

### Function Definition: `get_permissions()`

Note that you may provide a user-specified `permissions_dict` to extend the scope of this function, if need be. If `permissions_dict` is provided, the function will fall back to the default defined in it.

```py
permissions_dict = {'READ': 1, 'WRITE': 2, 'EDIT': 4, 'DELETE': 8}

def get_permissions(pnum = 0, permissions_dict = None):
    """
    Returns either a None for pnum=0,
    Or,
    a list of permission KEYWORDS.

    pnum = a non-negative integer
    permissions_dict: a dictionary specifying the permissions KEYWORDS
    >>>    If no permissions_dict is specified, it uses 
    >>>    a default permissions dictionary.
    """
    if permissions_dict is None:
        permissions_dict = {'READ': 1, 'WRITE': 2, 'EDIT': 4, 'DELETE': 8}
    # Max allowed value of pnum
    pnum_max = np.array(list(permissions_dict.values())).sum()
    if pnum==0:
        perm = None    
    else:
        if pnum>pnum_max:
            print("WARNING::: MAX allowed value of pnum = {}".format(pnum_max))
            pnum = pnum_max
        permissions = list(permissions_dict.keys())
        # Convert Decimal to Binary 
        #    ==> Convert to list of chars
        #        ==> Keep 4 chars: use str.zfill(4)
        #            ==> Flip Order 
        # Logic with Example: 
        # Dec(7) --> Bin(111) 
        #   ---> `0111` 
        #        ---> ['0','1','1','1'] 
        #            ---> ['1','1','1','0']
        p = list(str(int(bin(pnum)[2:])).zfill(4))
        p.reverse()
        # Extract permissions as KEYWORDS
        imax = len(permissions)
        perm = [permissions[i] for i,x in enumerate(p) if bool(int(x)) and i<imax]

    return perm
```

I hope this helps.