# How to stop code from repeating in all of the code

Tags: python

I’m new and still learning but I’m making a random character Generator and I don’t know how to make it stop or end the code and start a new one.

```
import random 
Rac = ["Human", "Half-Human", "Not Human"]
Race = random.choice(Rac)
Age = random.randint(1,100)
skil = [“Beserker”,”Mage”,”Assassin”]
Skill = random.choice(skil)
Gende = [“Male”,”Female”]
Gender = random.choice(Gende)

class human:
    def __dir__(self):
        return[Race,Age,Skill,Gender]

person = human()
print(dir(person))

print(“Race: {}, Age: {}, Class: {}, Gender: {}”.format(Race,Age,Class,Gender))
```

I have two of these but the ages keep printing out the same and I don’t know how to separate them so it’s a different age and not the same number for both.

I need to end the Age for that generator because it interferes and makes it all the same age, Instead of random ages.
Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please fix your code so that it runs without errors (the quotes got replaced).

Comment: @snwflk Yes, check my answer below. I have updated it.

Comment: I'm addressing the OP to [edit] the question itself.

Comment: @snwflk I get you! XDXD!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood,

First of all, I have corrected the code and removed syntax errors.
*(Below given code is **not** an answer. It is just the updated code. I have given my answer below that.)*

```py
import random 
Rac = ["Human", "Half-Human", "Not Human"]
Race = random.choice(Rac)
Age = random.randint(1,100)
skil = ["Beserker", "Mage", "Assassin"]
Skill = random.choice(skil)
Gende = ["Male", "Female"]
Gender = random.choice(Gende)

class human:
    def __dir__(self):
        return [Race, Age, Skill, Gender]

person = human()
print(dir(person))

print("Race: {}, Age: {}, Skill: {}, Gender: {}".format(Race, Age, Skill, Gender))
```

### My answer :

Now,
When you create the random object,
Here : `Age = random.randint(1,100)`
It gets called only once, so only one random number is generated and you are using it 2 times.

> I have two of these but the ages keep printing out the same and I don’t know how to separate them how do I separate them so it’s a different age and not the same number for both

What you need, is to generate this number inside the class definition. So it will get called every time you create the object of that class.

#### Code:

```py
import random
class human:
    def __dir__(self) -> list:
        self.Rac = ["Human", "Half-Human", "Not Human"]
        self.Race = random.choice(self.Rac)
        self.Age = random.randint(1,100)
        self.skil = ["Beserker", "Mage", "Assassin"]
        self.Skill = random.choice(self.skil)
        self.Gende = ["Male", "Female"]
        self.Gender = random.choice(self.Gende)
        return [self.Race, str(self.Age), self.Skill, self.Gender]

person = human()
print(dir(person))
```

**(Note the str() conversion of `self.Age`)**

### Now some other knowledge:

`dir()` method calls `__dir__` method in the class and `__dir__` is supposed to return list containing items of similar data types (int or str).
This means list should contain all integers or all strings.
For example, code:

```py
class Hello():
    def __dir__(self):
        return ["1", "2", "3"]

print(dir(Hello()))
```

Output: `['1', '2', '3']`

if:

```py
class Hello():
    def __dir__(self):
        return [1, "2", 3]

print(dir(Hello()))
```

Output: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

For more information: [What's the difference between dir() and __dir__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703335/whats-the-difference-between-dir-and-dir)